# How do I use PowerMockito to return a mock object from a final static class

Tags: java, testng, mockito, powermock

Hey I'm using Mockito and TestNG to write a unit test for a class that's making a lot of external calls to a service, I'm actually quite new to this hence I seem to be stuck with little documentation on the net for my exact problem.

my test looks like this basically

```
@Test
public class ClassToTestTest{

@Mock
private Object1 object1;

@Mock
private Object2 object2;

@InjectMocks
private ClassToTest classToTest;

public void test1(){
    classToTest.methodToTest();

}
...
...
}
```

The actual class is as follows

```
import FinalClass;

public class ClassToTest{

private Object1 object1;
private Object2 object2;

public void methodToTest(){
    object2 = FinalClass.getObject2();

    ...
    ...
}

...
...
}
```

I just need FinalClass.getObject2() to return the mock of Object2 That I've created in my Test, I know I can mock FinalClass using PowerMock, but I'm not quite getting how to inject it in the classToTest that I've created, so that when I run the classToTest.methodToTest() from my test object2 is initialized with my mocked implementation.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the annotation @PrepareForTest and the use of mockStatic() which are required when you wish to mock a final static class with PowerMockito. I think where you might be getting confused is that you're dealing with a `final static` class and not only a `final` class, so there are a few additional mock calls you need to be aware of.

Given these implementation classes

```
/*
The final static class that's giving you all the mocking grief
*/
public final class FinalStaticClass {

    // this object instance "will not" be returned when we mock() the class
    private static MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    public static MyObject getMyObject() {
        return obj; 
    }
}

/*
A simple value object used by MyClass
*/
public class MyObject {

}

/*
The class you wish to test
*/
public class MyClass {

    private MyObject obj;

    public void methodToTest() {
        obj = FinalStaticClass.getMyObject();
        // do something
    }

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Make sure you include `powermock-mockito-1.4.10-full.jar` in your project, then you can use this test class

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

import ...    

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FinalStaticClass.class)
public class MyClassTest{

    @Mock
    MyObject expectedObject;

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Test
    public void test1(){

        // mock all static methods
        mockStatic(FinalStaticClass.class);

        when(FinalStaticClass.getMyObject()).thenReturn(expectedObject);

        // execute the method under test
        myClass.methodToTest();

        assertEquals(expectedObject, myClass.getMyObject());

    }
}
```

You can see that `expectedObject` is a mock that you have created in the test and not the implementation returned from FinalStaticClass

Comment: Hey, I tried that I had put the @PrepareForTest annotation, it just gives me an error saying, cannot subclass final class, and yeah, in TestNG you can use the annotation at the class level. It converts all public void procedures into tests.

Comment: Updated answer with a working code example to address the `static final` nature of your class